# Visual Studio XAML preview error for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 with the latest Xamarin tooling we are getting the following warning when opening a `.xaml` file.

> Visual Studio requires a newer version of Windows to display this content.

I am aware that the window shown is the Windows .xaml live preview which is not supported by Xamarin and (I am not trying to preview), the issue is every time we open a `.xaml` file the preview window appears taking half the screen.

Is there any way to disable the preview window from opening by default- as it takes half the screen so needs to be closed before working on the file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the default editor that opens .xaml files.

1. right click on a XAML file in solution explorer and select "Open with"
2. In the dialog that opens, select XML (Text) Editor and click "Set as Default"

Now your XAML file should open by default with that simple XML editor.

Comment: I didn't expect intellisense to work when using the standard XML editor but I was pleasantly surprised, thanks.